# ODOO 11 : Modify Invoice look

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-11

In odoo 11, we have the choice between 4 layout when it comes to create invoices. When trying to modify one (not only the css but also the content), I started to modify the `external_layout_clean`, as a first test before writing my own.

**The problem**

here's what the QWeb looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="web.external_layout_clean">
  <div class="header o_clean_header">
    <div class="row">
      <<.... HEADER CONTENT ....>>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="article o_report_layout_clean">
    <t t-raw="0"/>
  </div>

  <div class="footer o_clean_footer">
    <div class="row mt8">
      << .... FOOTER CONTENT .... >>
    </div>
  </div>
</t>
```

So modifying the header and the footer is easy. But the most important part, **the body, does not appear here.**

`o_clean_footer` can be found in `o_clean_footer.less` file, it's just some cssless. When you remove it from the code above, the style disappear. But when you remove the `article` class, everything disappear. So I don't know how, but this **css class** contain all the information.

**The question**

where to find the article class, especially the part that is the vector of datas?

Maybe we're just not meant to modify like that, then how should I modify it?

*NB: In openerp, this was modified straight in a view, like for the header, I don't know how this works in odoo 11. I found some clue about odoo 10, but it seems like it was different*

Comment: If you know the template names (t-name for example) you can search for them under Settings/Technica/User Interface/Views. Activate the QWeb filter. The content templates of a report can be easily reached by clicking the smart button "QWeb views" on the report formular at Settings/Technical/Reports/Reports.

Comment: @CZoellner Thank you, yes I did found it as stated in the post, it's `external_layout_clean`, but it's the inside I'm not understanding.

Comment: You can find the invoice report document at https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/account/views/report_invoice.xml